# Mongoose Schema number field to be at exact length

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have this moongoose schema:

```
var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 24
    },

    lastname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        min: 3,
        max: 24
    },

    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        min: 9,
        max: 9
    },

    mediations: [assetSchema]
});
```

when I try to add a new user with the id **111222333** I get the next validation error:

```
{
   "errors": {
        "id": {
            "message": "Path `id` (111222333) is more than maximum allowed value (9).",
            "name": "ValidatorError",
            "properties": {
                "max": 9,
                "type": "max",
                "message": "Path `{PATH}` ({VALUE}) is more than maximum allowed value (9).",
                "path": "id",
                "value": 111222333
            },
            "kind": "max",
            "path": "id",
            "value": 111222333,
            "$isValidatorError": true
        }
    },
    "_message": "User validation failed",
    "message": "User validation failed: id: Path `id` (111222333) is more than maximum allowed value (9).",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Is there any other way to validate a `Number` type field to be in an exact length?
or did I misunderstood the way mongoose stores numbers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`min` and `max` **do not** mean allowed amount of digits in the `Number` provided, as the error say:

> (320981350) is more than **maximum allowed value** (9)

What they mean is an actual minimum / maximum value of the field with `Number` type, so for example in

```
{
    type: Number,
    min : 101,
    max : 999
}
```

- the maximum `Number` allowed is `999`
- the minimum `Number` allowed is `101`

In your case, if you have 9-digit numbers as your `id`, define the field in schema like:

```
{
    type: Number,
    min : 100000000,
    max : 999999999
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to write a custom validator

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        validate: {
            validator: function(val) {
                return val.toString().length === 9
            },
            message: val => `${val.value} has to be 9 digits`
        }
    }
   
})
```

Read more about [custom validations](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators)

Answer (score 1):

`min` or `max` does not mean `min-length` or `max-length` ...

So to achieve your goal you better set this as your schema:

```
{
    type: Number,
    min: 100000000,
    max: 999999999
}
```

take a look at mongoose documentation:
[mongoose Doc](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema-number-js)